# Herramientas para comprobar el funcionamiento de una aplicación móvil

Tags: java, android, android-studio, funciones, programación-móvil

necesito recomendaciones de programas o paginas que sirvan para testear el funcionamiento de una aplicación móvil recién creada.

Específicamente para validar funcionamientos de carga (load test), rendimiento (perfomance test) y estrés (stress test).

Comment: Existen varios frameworks o servicios pero esto, puedes usar Monkey https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey